# Determine an object's validity

Tags: javascript

**Context**:

I'm trying to make sure that an object passed to a function is valid before I use it. And I'd like to know if there is any difference between the two approaches, one is more syntactically verbose than the other. If the functionality and behaviors are the same across all JavaScript engines used by modern user agents such Chrome, IE, FF etc., I'd rather use the simpler version. If not, I'd like to use the safe bet so my code behaves as I intended regardless of the JavaScript engine's implementation.

**Question**:

Given the following function, there are two statements as denoted by comment section.
Does statement 1 yield the same result as statement 2 regardless of the JS engine (or user agents)? And why or why not?

```
function f(obj) {
   if(obj) { // statement 1
     console.log('obj is valid');
   }
   if(obj !== null && obj!==undefined) { // statement 2
     console.log('obj is invalid');
   }
}
```

Comment: I prefer `typeof obj !== "undefined" && obj !== null` your first one is almost as good and your second one is identical I think, but mine won't give an error if you use it with an array index that doesn't exist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, they are different.

`if (obj)` tests for *truthy* values.  In JavaScript everything is truthy except for `""`, `0`, `false`, `NaN`, `null` and `undefined` (there may be a few more I'm forgetting...)

But what if one of those falsy value is a value you are ok with, such as zero or `false`?  A `quantity` of zero is a perfectly legit value, as is `false` for `isTotallyLame`.  So you need a test that allows those values to pass.  You need to test for *existence*.

`if (obj!==null && obj!==undefined)` tests for *existence*.  Only `null` or `undefined` will fail the test.  This means that empty string `""`, zero `0`, or even `false` are valid values because they are a set value.

---

However, as @Tim notes, the preferred standard test for existence looks like this:

```
if (typeof obj !== "undefined" && obj !== null)
```

Comment: great answers and comments, exactly what I need to know.  thanks guys!